# How to use startsWith in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
let botmod = staff.get(`${message.author.id}`)
  if (botmod.startsWith !== "Bot")
    return message.channel.send("Unfortunately, you are a server mod. You can't use bot commands.")
```

The above is an example of me trying to use `.startsWith()`. However, I don't think I am using it correctly. 
It triggers that message, even if the message does have `Bot` in it.
There are no errors logged in the console.

Comment: There's not enough in your post to provide an answer since there's no way to tell what `staff.get` returns; however, `String.prototype.startsWith` is a method and needs parentheses.

Comment: Documentation is always your friend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is a function, you pass the value you want to check and it will return a `boolean`, so

```
if (botmod.startsWith("Bot")) 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a function:
If you want the string to start with Bot,

```
if(botmod.startsWith("Bot")){
  // ...do stuff
}
```

or
If you don't want the string to start with Bot,

```
if(!botmod.startsWith("Bot")){
  // ...do stuff
}
```

However, you can only run `.startsWith()` on Strings.

Answer (score 1):

[startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) returns a boolean.  So you want

```
const foo = 'bar';

if(foo.startsWith('thing')) {
   // do stuff
}
```